# calling an array from another web page?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a website and can't understand how to pass arrays across different web pages of the same website. The code for defining the array is:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("hello", JSON.stringify(["hi", "sup"]));
```

The code for calling the array on the second page is:

```
var helloArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("hello"));
```

When I loop through the array with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < helloArray.length; i++) {
  // JavaScript code
}
```

It creates an error that says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

What can I change and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe you want `localStorage` instead? From the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage): *"This is a global object (`sessionStorage`) that maintains a storage area that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated."*

Comment: Sessions should really only be used to store strings. They're unreliable with other forms of information. Try storing it as a string and recovering it as a hash/JSON.

Comment: oh my gosh! your idea worked Felix Kling. you are my hero!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 2):

Use localStorage like this:

**- To write content:**

```
localStorage.setItem("hello", JSON.stringify(["hi", "sup"]));
```

**- To read content:**

```
var helloArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hello'));
```

[Here JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/1L9z35y6/1/)